# Why are my kids naked?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

[image: Children in underwear only]

I was playing my old Hearthfire save in Skyrim when I've noticed that my kids were only wearing their underwear. I attempted to give them clothes, but they didn't do anything with them.

Anyone else have a solution?

**EDIT**: Now the rest of the Skyrim kids aren't wearing clothes.

Comment: Kids their age don't like to follow rules. It's a phase. It'll pass as they grow older.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**The "definition of insanity" solution**

There appears to be a glitch in Hearthfire where giving your kids clothes can make them naked.  The solution to this appears to be to give them *more* clothes.

It's possible that an unrelated glitch made them naked in the first place, and then giving them clothes made them naked-er.  Giving them another set might be enough to fix the problem.

**The "abandonment" solution**

Many bugs in Skyrim can be rectified by leaving the area long enough that the area resets.  For this to work, you've got to leave the house (and the general area - get far away for best results) and then take it easy for about 10 consecutive days.  You won't win any parent-of-the-year awards, but you might get your kids clothes back on them.

**The "put that down" solution**

If you're playing on PC, you can try emptying out their inventory and then giving them clothes again to see if they'll wear them.  **As always, back up your save before playing with the console!**

1. Open the console by pressing the <kbd>~</kbd> key
2. Click on the child.
3. Enter the command `removeallitems player` - this will put everything in the child's inventory into yours.
4. Disable the child with `disable`
5. Enable the child with `enable`

Now try giving them their clothes back, and seeing if they put them on.

Comment: And now I'm probably flagged in some government database for searching for "naked kids" in a video game...

Comment: Ok the tedious part is going to so this to every skyrim kid

Comment: no one likes naked tag

Comment: Yeah, the part where you disable your kids is going to raise some eyebrows, too...

Comment: @DaveTheGamer, [here's another console command gem](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Children): `Changing a child's race through the console revokes their imperviousness. For example, entering "setrace khajiit" allows the child to be killed. Doing so causes cosmetic glitches. In this example, the child appears as a Khajiit with a human head; if the child is female, breasts and a bra appear on it.`

Comment: @agent86 I decided to do a bit of testing with that, and it seems I may have found the bug mentioned for the question.  I tried putting adult clothes on a child, and it would remove the related part - IE, armor caused them to appear with just underwear, boots caused them to appear barefoot.  Using `setrace` caused them to gain the armor I had added.  So, it seems that the issue is caused by the children trying to equip items which are not allowed to be equipped by children.

Comment: @Namfuak, that was my assumption as well - something in their inventory incompatible with their character model overriding their default clothes.  [One account said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98628/how-do-i-give-gifts-to-children?rq=1) their kids were holding several hundred baskets, and that it was some sort of glitch.

Comment: Technically (at least, if it hasn't changed since *Oblivion*), the console is opened by whichever key is left of `1`. On US keyboards, that's `~`, but it varies with locale.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - Not only is he disabling them, but giving them booze as well! (Enabling)

Comment: For some reason, giving the NPC a grey dress (#0300d820) displayed as if wearing no clothes. `removeallitems` didn't add the item to my inventory and giving another grey dress didn't seem to change anything, but I tried a blue one (#0300d81e) and it wore the clothing.

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to fix this bug.

All you have to do is make sure you've given your kids a wooden sword and child's doll (sometimes they will be in the hidden chest in Salvius Farm outside Markarth).

Give them the clothes while they're in action either playing with toys or sitting down. But you cant rush through, after you give them the clothes let the dialog run its course completely and they should put their clothes back on.

It took me forever to figure this out, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the command "equipitem", then you have to put a "1" after the command to ensure it stays on permanently. Command should be "equipitem (item id) 1".

Answer (score 1):

Wiki says:

> - Upon downloading Hearthfire, there is a chance that none of the children in game will be wearing clothes. This includes children eligible for adoption. There is currently no known fix.

That's because you just downloaded Hearthfire and the children are naked.

Answer (score -3):

There is a mod called Children wear all where they will wear whatever adults wear including modded clothing. It's on the Nexus and Steam both. Just search for Children Wear All. If that doesn't work, search for children clothing.

Comment: This question is so old and and already has an answer. Also I don't think he needs mods and he just wants the kids to wear clothes. He didn't says we wanted them to wear specific clothes, he just wanted to make them unnaked. -1